# Interface entre python e prolog

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-2.7, prolog

Preciso fazer a comunicação entre o prolog e Python. Acabei encontrando um API pySwip que faz a interface entre essas 2 tecnologias, mas não consigo faze-la funcionar porque o prolog precisa ser instalado como shared library. Já segui alguns tutoriais (um deles é este aqui [1](https://github.com/tjvr/pyswip/blob/master/INSTALL) ) de instalação mas eles não deram certo.

segue a página do pyswip: [2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyswip)

Comment: Olá @Roney você vai usar pyhton agora é? Já tentou usar  [PyLog](http://cdsoft.fr/pylog/index.html)

Comment: entao @fernandoandrade eu to testando possibilidades ainda haha obrigado pela atenção cara